# time 00:00:00 is being stored in my database while using df.to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

i have a table in my pandas dataframe.

```
id count
1   12
2   4
3   7
4   3
5   9
```

i defined a string

```
dateSelect = "'2016-11-20'"
```

i wanted to add a new column to my df `dates` as a constant value in my `dateSelect`

so i did`df['dates'] = pd.Timestamp(dateSelect)`

and i got result

```
id count dates
1   12   2016-11-20
2   4    2016-11-20
3   7    2016-11-20
4   3    2016-11-20
5   9    2016-11-20
```

(also tried using

```
df['dates'] = dateSelect
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

)

now, i was storing this dataframe in my database using `sqlalchemy`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://name:pwd@xxx.xxx.xx.xx/dbname', echo=False)
df.to_sql(name='date_test', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

when i was querying from my database

```
select * from date_test;
```

i am getting the following results.

```
id count dates
1   12   2016-11-20 00:00:00
2   4    2016-11-20 00:00:00
3   7    2016-11-20 00:00:00
4   3    2016-11-20 00:00:00
5   9    2016-11-20 00:00:00
```

but i didnot wanted the time to come there.
is there any other way to query in my dataframe such that these `00:00:00` will not come in my database.

P.S i don't want to make any changes in my table in database once it is stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try converting datetime into a date object and then write to sql.

```
dateSelect = '2016-11-20'
df['dates'] = dateSelect
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.date
```

Hope this helps.